# Compiling Octave MXE nsi-installer with --enable-64

Tags: c++, gcc, octave, mxe

I am trying to compile an Octave nsi-installer for Windows with --enable-64 for large array support.

Attempt 1: Using a Linux Mint virtual machine on Windows 10:

./configure shows everything seems to be OK, and after running make, quite a lot completes. However, several minutes into "[build]    default-octave", it crashes out. Looking at the log, when trying to link liboctave/.libs/liboctave-3.dll, it says:

> libgnu/.libs/libgnu.a(lock.o): In function `glthread_recursive_lock_init_multithreaded':
>   /home/mike/temp/mxe-octave-3fc30cd416ac/tmp-default-octave/octave-4.1.0+/libgnu/glthread/lock.c:289: undefined reference to`__imp_pthread_mutexattr_init'
>   /home/mike/temp/mxe-octave-3fc30cd416ac/tmp-default-octave/octave-4.1.0+/libgnu/glthread/lock.c:292: undefined reference to `__imp_pthread_mutexattr_settype'
>   /home/mike/temp/mxe-octave-3fc30cd416ac/tmp-default-octave/octave-4.1.0+/libgnu/glthread/lock.c:298: undefined reference to`__imp_pthread_mutex_init'
>   /home/mike/temp/mxe-octave-3fc30cd416ac/tmp-default-octave/octave-4.1.0+/libgnu/glthread/lock.c:304: undefined reference to `__imp_pthread_mutexattr_destroy'
>   /home/mike/temp/mxe-octave-3fc30cd416ac/tmp-default-octave/octave-4.1.0+/libgnu/glthread/lock.c:301: undefined reference to`__imp_pthread_mutexattr_destroy'
>   /home/mike/temp/mxe-octave-3fc30cd416ac/tmp-default-octave/octave-4.1.0+/libgnu/glthread/lock.c:295: undefined reference to `__imp_pthread_mutexattr_destroy'
>   libgnu/.libs/libgnu.a(strsignal.o): In function`init':
>   /home/mike/temp/mxe-octave-3fc30cd416ac/tmp-default-octave/octave-4.1.0+/libgnu/strsignal.c:143: undefined reference to `__imp_pthread_key_create'
>   libgnu/.libs/libgnu.a(strsignal.o): In function`free_key_mem':
>   /home/mike/temp/mxe-octave-3fc30cd416ac/tmp-default-octave/octave-4.1.0+/libgnu/strsignal.c:170: undefined reference to `__imp_pthread_setspecific'
>   libgnu/.libs/libgnu.a(strsignal.o): In function`strsignal':
>   /home/mike/temp/mxe-octave-3fc30cd416ac/tmp-default-octave/octave-4.1.0+/libgnu/strsignal.c:101: undefined reference to `__imp_pthread_once'
>   libgnu/.libs/libgnu.a(strsignal.o): In function`getbuffer':
>   /home/mike/temp/mxe-octave-3fc30cd416ac/tmp-default-octave/octave-4.1.0+/libgnu/strsignal.c:186: undefined reference to `__imp_pthread_getspecific'
>   /home/mike/temp/mxe-octave-3fc30cd416ac/tmp-default-octave/octave-4.1.0+/libgnu/strsignal.c:195: undefined reference to`__imp_pthread_setspecific'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

So, the problem is all these undefined references to '__imp_pthread_' functions in lock.c.

When I look at lock.c at those lines, the code shows:

```
  err = pthread_mutexattr_init (&attributes);
```

So my main question is, why in linking is '__imp_' added to the front of the function?

If I 'nm libpthread.so', I see stuff like:

> pthread_mutexattr_init.o:
>   0000000000000000 T __pthread_mutexattr_init
>   0000000000000000 T pthread_mutexattr_init

So the functions are in there, but the link doesn't see them because the '__imp_' is attached? I don't understand...

The log shows that '-pthread' is used rather than '-lpthread', which I think is what is recommended. When I look at the top of the log, it shows:

> checking for the pthreads library -lpthreads... no
>
> checking whether pthreads work without any flags... no
>
> checking whether pthreads work with -Kthread... no
>
> checking whether pthreads work with -kthread... no
>
> checking for the pthreads library -llthread... no
>
> checking whether pthreads work with -pthread... yes
>
> checking for joinable pthread attribute... PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE
>
> checking if more special flags are required for pthreads... no

Attempt 2: Using a CentOS linux system:

Similar to above, ./configure works but a little ways into "[build]    default-octave", it crashes out. Looking at the log, it says:

```
/u/glaucus-r1/mpjohnso/octave/mxe-octave-3fc30cd416ac/tmp-default-octave/octave-4.1.0+/liboctave/array/dim-vector.h: In instantiation of 'dim_vector::dim_vector(octave_idx_type, octave_idx_type, Ints ...) [with Ints = {int}; octave_idx_type = long long int]':
/u/glaucus-r1/mpjohnso/octave/mxe-octave-3fc30cd416ac/tmp-default-octave/octave-4.1.0+/libinterp/octave-value/ov-typeinfo.h:203:85:   required from here
/u/glaucus-r1/mpjohnso/octave/mxe-octave-3fc30cd416ac/tmp-default-octave/octave-4.1.0+/liboctave/array/dim-vector.h:215:5: error: unable to deduce std::initializer_list<_Tp>&&' from '{r, c, lengths#0}'

     for (const auto l: {r, c, lengths...})
     ^
```

So, there seems to be some problem with how the '{r, c, lengths...}' line is interpreted... My first try used GCC 4.4.7, but the same thing happened once upgrading to GCC 6.2.0.

Any thoughts for either?

Comment: the error you are seeing about `{r, c, lengths...}` is not the latest version of Octave. It was already fixed a few weeks ago http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/rev/7a6279f4018f

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded the latest version (mxe-octave-851b9f4a6b1c) but now it fails trying to download default-octave with 404 not found errors from the various servers.

Comment: It finally started downloading, but now it's giving me the same pthread undefined reference stuff as described in Attempt 1.